# Configured all set for In-App Purchase, but still my product count is 0 - Swift 4

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, swift4

I have never integrate IAP before, I am trying to integrate IAP in my iOS App first time, I have search lots of articles on internet, I followed all of them to resolve my issue, but I don't have any idea how to solve it.

I have full filled **Agreement Tax and Banking**, now Its status is Active.

[image]

I have added new user in sandbox tester.

[image]

I have choose **Non-Renewing Subscription** in features menu, now It's status is **Ready To Submit**,

[image]

1. I have again and again removed application in device (iPhone XR and iPad 5).
2. I have been waited for a long time, approx 5 to 7 days for activation.
3. I have already enabled **In-App Purchase** flag from capabilities.
4. My Development Profile is also consider with **In-App Purchase**.
5. I have sign out (iTunes account) my all device (iPhone XR and iPad 5).
6. My Product ID is relevant with my Bundle ID.

My Code is below...

```
func IAPintegrate(){
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            let productId : NSSet = NSSet(objects: IAP_DEV_PRODUCT_ID)
            productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productId as! Set<String>)
            productsRequest.delegate = self
            productsRequest.start()
        }
    }
```

I have also added Delegate methods,

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print(response.products)
        let count : Int = response.products.count
        if (count>0) {

            let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
            if (validProduct.productIdentifier == IAP_DEV_PRODUCT_ID) {
                print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
                print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
                print(validProduct.price)
                self.buyProduct(product: validProduct)
            } else {
                print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
            }
        } else {
            print("nothing")
        }
    }
```

**still my product count is always 0** please help me what should i do ?

Comment: Did you set pricing for your product? I think you are missing something, incorrect bundle id or incorrect product id. I don't think there can be anything else

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Yes, I have set the product price, my bundle ID and product both are correct. still i face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are getting any product identifier strings that is invalid in `didReceive` response method.

```
print("Invalid product identifiers \(response.invalidProductIdentifiers)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is shown in your third screen shot. Your in-app purchases are Ready To Submit. That means they have not yet been *submitted and approved*. Therefore, as far as the store is concerned, they don't exist.